# Making parameters work in Azure .NET C# Spark Notebook

Tags: c#, apache-spark, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I tried to pass a string parameter into a Spark NoteBook written entirely in .NET Spark C# No matter what I tried it did not work.  What finally did work was to

1. Define the notebook as PySharp
2. Define the parameter - PySharp
3. Put the parameter value in a temporary table - PySharp
4. Then from C# I could pull the value from the temporary table and perform my logic.

See the example code at the bottom but does anyone have a way to make this work in C# without all of the jumping around?

```
--- parameter cell ---
sourcefilepath = "test" 
--- cell 1 ---
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType

schema = StructType([ StructField("sourcefilepath",StringType(),True)])
df = spark.createDataFrame([[sourcefilepath]],schema)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("sourcefilepathTable") ;

--- cell 2 ---
%%csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql;
using Microsoft.Spark.Sql.Types;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO ;
using System.Text.Json;

using System.IO.Compression ;
var dfSql = spark.Sql("Select sourcefilepath from sourcefilepathTable");

string sourcefilepath = dfSql.First().GetAs<string>("sourcefilepath");

-- remainder of my code goes here
```

Comment: Can you please include what you have tried in c#?

Comment: string sourcefilepath = "" ;